# Deploying Web Applications using Team Build and Web Deploy

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, webdeploy

So, here is the deal. In web app project settings I configured a deployment package which includes all content files along with IIS settings for the site & app pool. Now, when i go to Team Build build config, I use the following arguments to deploy the site.

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True 
/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://<servername>:8172/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="mysite.com" 
/p:UserName=<domain>\<user> 
/p:Password=<password>
```

While this actually works, the deployment will fail if "mysite.com" site doesn't exist on the destination server or if the app pool isn't set up correctly (i.e. ASP.NET version mismatch). So i find myself creating this stuff manually before i can deploy anything from Team Build. Is there a way to automate this? Am i missing some kind of argument switch? I guess another way to phrase this question, is why do i have to set all this up when the package includes all of IIS settings and should just deploy.

Thanks for any help/explanation.

**EDIT:**

I'm not entirely sure if this is true, but i believe i will not be able to do create site/app pool. From my understanding of things, Team Build uses msbuild to talk to msdeploy and that link is very limited in what it can do. So, I may be looking at changing the build workflow template to execute the command line to deploy the package (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the TechNet documentation on the iisApp provider at
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569054(WS.10).aspx. Of the four parameters, these are the ones you'd probably be interested in:

- managedRuntimeVersion
- skipAppCreation

Comment: I pretty much gave up trying to deploy with IIS settings attached. I was getting some sort of generic MSDeploy error. Nothing in the logs anywhere. No indication of what was failing. Typical Microsoft tech charlie foxtrot. So, i'm using Team Deploy to just copy the files over and still need have the initial setup in IIS on the remote server.